# Reading a multiple line .txt file into an array Python

Tags: python, arrays

I have a text file formatted as follows

```
a,b,c,d,e,f,
g,h,i,j,k,l,
```

How would I read this and store it as an array that looks like `[[a,b,c,d,e,f],[g,h,i,j,k,l]]`?

Comment: Are `a`, `b`, etc strings here?

Comment: try splitting by "," and "\n" by my logic that will create a list with 2 lists with the values

Comment: Did you even bother searching? There are dozens, if not hundreds, of stack overflow posts about reading csv files.

Answer (score 2):

When reading comma separated values from a file, it is easiest to use Python's CSV library, for example:

```
import csv

with open('input.csv', 'rb') as f_input:
    data = list(csv.reader(f_input))

print data
```

This also then copes with the case when the entries contain a comma (and is enclosed in quotes). For example this should contain 6 cells:

```
a,b,c,"d,e,f",h,i
```

Answer (score 1):

```
with open('yourfile.txt') as f:
    lines = [line.strip().split(',') for line in f]
```

Comment: Would this not create an empty element at the end of each inner list?

Comment: no, it would create a useless list around the inner list and leave the newline on the last char. edited accordingly